Why using "with" and "firstOrFail" methods in one request raised error on not found data?
On my Laravel/Livewire site, I'm trying to handle a case where an invalid slug is caught using the firstOrFail method:
class PointShowPage extends Component
{
    public string $slug;
    public $pointItem;

    public function mount(?string $slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        try {
            $this->pointItem = Point
                ::getBySlug($this->slug)
                ->with('creator')
                ->firstOrFail();
        } catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
            request()->session()->flash('error', 'Point Page not found !');
            return $this->redirect(route('home'), navigate: true);
        }
    }
}

I have a scope in my model:
public function scopeGetBySlug($query, $slug = null)
{
    return $query->where(with(new Point)->getTable() . '.slug', $slug);
}

However, I'm encountering an error:

Call to a member function with() on null

It seems like I can't use with with the firstOrFail method. How can I correctly catch an error here and make a redirect?
I'm using the following versions:

"laravel/framework": "^10.48.4"
"livewire/livewire": "^3.4.9"
"spatie/laravel-honeypot": "^4.5"

Error DETAILS:
I tried to remake it in other way :
$this->newsItem = Point
    ::getBySlug($this->slug.'KKK')
    ->getByPublished(PointPublishedEnum::PUBLISHED)
    ->firstOrFail();
$this->newsItem->load('creator');
$this->newsItem->load('newsCategory');

But the same error on first request above and full error log is :
[2024-04-17 16:03:19] local.ERROR: Call to a member function with() on null {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function with() on null at PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/HigherOrderTapProxy.php:34)
[stacktrace]
#0 PointeresApp/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Drawer/Utils.php(154): Illuminate\\Support\\HigherOrderTapProxy->__call()
#1 PointeresApp/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Mechanisms/HandleComponents/HandleComponents.php(275): Livewire\\Drawer\\Utils::generateBladeView()
#2 PointeresApp/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Mechanisms/HandleComponents/HandleComponents.php(230): Livewire\\Mechanisms\\HandleComponents\\HandleComponents->getView()
#3 PointeresApp/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Mechanisms/HandleComponents/HandleComponents.php(53): Livewire\\Mechanisms\\HandleComponents\\HandleComponents->render()
#4 PointeresApp/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/LivewireManager.php(72): Livewire\\Mechanisms\\HandleComponents\\HandleComponents->mount()
#5 PointeresApp/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Features/SupportPageComponents/HandlesPageComponents.php(17): Livewire\\LivewireManager->mount()
#6 PointeresApp/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Features/SupportPageComponents/SupportPageComponents.php(118): Livewire\\Component->Livewire\\Features\\SupportPageComponents\\{closure}()
#7 PointeresApp/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Features/SupportPageComponents/HandlesPageComponents.php(14): Livewire\\Features\\SupportPageComponents\\SupportPageComponents::interceptTheRenderOfTheComponentAndRetreiveTheLayoutConfiguration()
#8 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(46): Livewire\\Component->__invoke()
#9 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(259): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#10 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(205): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#11 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(806): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#12 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(144): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#13 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#14 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#15 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#16 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#17 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#18 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#19 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#20 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()
#21 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
#22 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#23 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#24 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#25 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()
#26 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#27 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(805): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#28 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(784): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#29 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(748): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#30 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(737): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#31 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#32 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(144): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#33 PointeresApp/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Features/SupportDisablingBackButtonCache/DisableBackButtonCacheMiddleware.php(19): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#34 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Livewire\\Features\\SupportDisablingBackButtonCache\\DisableBackButtonCacheMiddleware->handle()
#35 PointeresApp/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(66): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#36 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar->handle()
#37 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#38 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#39 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#40 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#41 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#42 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#43 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#44 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#45 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(99): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#46 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#47 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#48 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle()
#49 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#50 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle()
#51 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#52 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#53 PointeresApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#54 PointeresApp/public/index.php(51): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#55 {main}
"}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
ATTEMPT TO FIX :
I tried to check in your way and see that error is on the second line :
 Point::findOrFail('wrong ID')

I tried to clear relations/traits from this model and now this model has :
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Enums\PointPublishedEnum;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
class Point extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'point';


    protected $fillable  = [ 'id', 'company_id', 'point_category_id', 'title',  'slug', 'content', 'content_shortly',
            'creator_id', 'is_homepage', 'is_top', 'published', 'image', 'source_type', 'source_url', 'youtube_key',
            'updated_at', 'published_at',
        ];



    protected $casts = [ 'created_at' => 'datetime', 'updated_at' => 'datetime', 'published_at' => 'datetime' ];


    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function ($point) {
            if (Storage::exists($point->image)) {
                Storage::delete($point->image);
            }
        });
    }
    
    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'creator_id');
    }

    public function pointCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PointCategory::class/*, 'creator_id'*/);
    }



    public function scopeGetByTitle($query, $title = null, $extendedSearch = false)
    {
        if (empty($title)) {
            return $query;
        }
        $prefix = DB::getTablePrefix();
        $tb = $this->table . ($prefix ?? $prefix) . '.';

        if ( ! $extendedSearch) {
            return $query->whereRaw($this->table . ".title like '%" . addslashes($title) . "%' ");
        }

        return $query->whereRaw(" ( " . $tb . "title like '%" . addslashes($title) . "%' " . ' OR ' .
                                $tb . "content like '%" . addslashes($title) . "%' " . ' OR ' .
                                $tb . "content_shortly like '%" . addslashes($title) . "%' ) ");
    }

    public function scopeGetById($query, int $id = null)
    {
        if (empty($id)) {
            return $query;
        }

        return $query->where($this->table . '.id', $id);
    }


    public function scopeGetByPublished($query, PointPublishedEnum $published = null)
    {
        if ( ! isset($published->value) or strlen($published->value) == 0) {
            return $query;
        }

        return $query->where($this->table . '.published', $published->value);
    }

    public function scopeGetOnlyPublished($query)
    {
        return $query->where($this->table . '.published', PointPublishedEnum::PUBLISHED);
    }


    public function scopeGetByIsHomepage($query, $is_homepage = null)
    {
        if ( ! isset($is_homepage) or strlen($is_homepage) == 0) {
            return $query;
        }

        return $query->where($this->table . '.is_homepage', $is_homepage);
    }

    public function scopeGetByIsTop($query, $is_top = null)
    {
        if ( ! isset($is_top) or strlen($is_top) == 0) {
            return $query;
        }

        return $query->where($this->table . '.is_top', $is_top);
    }



    public function comments(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'model_id', 'id');
    }

    public function tasks(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }

}

Any ideas what raised this error and how to debug/fix it ?

First Check what the scopeGetBySlug() returns by using dd() inside it like. dd($slug, $query) It will check whether you are getting the correct arguments.

if scopeGetBySlug is a method inside the Point class, shouldn't $this->getTable() be used instead of with(new Point)->getTable() ?

with dd($slug, $query) I see slug string value and Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#967 ▼ // app/Models/Point.php:228
I supose these are the correct arguments

@PetroGromovo all this point that the cause is not what you shared in your post. Try to use simple code like Point::first() and Point::findOrFail('wrong ID') and debug the component that needs an instance to not generate that error. (speculating: somewhere you have somthing like $record->relation->with()->get();)

Please read ATTEMPT TO FIX
